# MySQL detect field order pattern?

Tags: mysql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
cid  |  tid  |  score
-----+-------+-------
 6   |  383  |   88
 2   |  234  |   91
 3   |  685  |   77
 5   |  543  |   97
etc...
```

What I am trying to do is find an ordinal field pattern in the tid column, then search for other instances of that pattern in the same column.  For example:

I query to display all tids of a single cid, ordered by descending score:

```
cid  |  tid  |  score
-----+-------+-------
 6   |  909  |  100
 6   |  119  |   99
 6   |  221  |   98
 6   |  765  |   97
etc...
```

A pattern is established in the tid column: 909, 119, 221, 765.  Now I want to find other possible instances of that pattern, where the cid value is something else.  (Note: different cids can have the same tids, so cid 6 can have tid 909, and cid 4 can too.)

I want to check for the pattern in a second query.  The pattern values can be spaced out, but they must appear in order:

```
                           QUERY 2:    
cid  |  tid  |  score           cid    tid     score
---------------------         ---------------------
 6   |  909  |  100             5    | 909 < | 100
 6   |  119  |   99             5    | 831   |  97
 6   |  221  |   98             5    | 793   |  96
 6   |  765  |   97             5    | 435   |  96
                                5    | 404   |  95
                                5    | 119 < |  94
                                5    | 221 < |  94
                                5    | 765 < |  94
```

After the comparison, I would like MySQL to return something like:

```
cid |  tid pattern  | instances (in order)
----+---------------+----------------------
 5      909               1 (or 0)
 5      119               1 (or 0)
 5      221               1 (or 0)
 5      765               1 (or 0)
```

Is there a reasonable way to do this in MySQL?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: You haven't really specified very clearly what the `instances` column does. What if you have '119, 221, 765, 909'? Is it the 909 that isn't in order, or is it the 119, 221 and 765 that aren't in order? You need to give some more explanation of how this column should work in a variety of situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnerally this kind of operation doesn't work well across rows - Start by pulling it into a single record per cid:

```
 INSERT INTO summary (c_id, tids)
 SELECT cid, GROUP_CONCAT(tid ORDER BY score DESC)
 FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY cid;
```

Then you can easily get a list of all combinations where the patterns match or are a superset:

```
 SELECT a.cid, a.tids, b.cid, b.tids
 FROM summary a, summary b
 WHERE a.cid<>b.cid
 AND a.cid=6
 AND b.tids LIKE CONCAT('%', a.tids, '%');
```

You might want to have a look at levenstein functions or convolution (hint: if you're not analysing genomes then have a look at some code which does).

Comment: Good idea.  I hadn't thought of using GROUP_CONCAT.  Thanks.